# Why won't my C++ code compile, getting undefined reference error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, program-entry-point

For my class assignment, we had to make a C++ program using a class and then compile it. These are the following.

`Snake.h`

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// We need to include string since we need to access it
#include <string>
using std::string;
// Our declaration of our class
class Snake
{
public:
    // These are our properties
    string color;
    double length;
    bool venomous;

    // Our two constructors, this is basically saying the snake is able to create these datatypes.
    // It can either have a default data used or inputted data when called.
    Snake()
    {
    }
    // This one has the parameters
    Snake(string color, double length, bool venomous)
    {
    }

    // Our functions that we are declaring so we can use them in snake.cpp
    // These aren't declared here because we don't have any data yet that they can use
    // We also are just telling the code that they are here and that they may or
    // may not be called at some point

    void display();
    void bite();
};

#endif
```

`Snake.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Snake.h"

// These creates our data from the header file.
// Snake is seen below with the default data and then Snake with the parameters can be seen.
Snake::Snake()
{
    color = "Red";
    length = 12.5;
    venomous = false;
}

Snake::Snake(string newColor, double newLength, bool newVenomous)
{
    color = newColor;
    length = newLength;
    venomous = newVenomous;
}

// These initalize these functions so that they can be used when we do our dot callback in our main.
void Snake::bite()
{
    cout << "This snake bites because he is hungry";
}

void Snake::display()
{
    cout << "The color of the snake is: " << color;
    cout << "The length of the snake is: " << length;
    cout << "Is the snake venomous: " << venomous;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Snake.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // We create our first snake
    Snake snake1;
    // Now we need to call method that our object contains
    snake1.display();
    snake1.bite();

    // UI is user input
    bool UIVenomous;
    string UIColor, isVenomous;
    double UILength;

    cout << "What color is the snake?" << endl;
    cin >> UIColor;
    cout << "How long is the snake? " << endl;
    cin >> UILength;
    cout << "Is the snake venomous? (y/n) " << endl;
    cin >> isVenomous;
    if (isVenomous == "y")
    {
        UIVenomous = true;
    }
    else if (isVenomous == "n")
    {
        UIVenomous = false;
    }

    // We now call our class and set our object with the variables from above
    Snake snake2(UIColor, UILength, UIVenomous);
    // We need to now call our methods that our object has
    snake2.display();
    snake2.bite();
}
```

I am using VSCode and when I try to run build task it gives me this error

```
C:\Users\viens\AppData\Local\Temp\cclzLMka.o: In function `main':
c:/Users/viens/OneDrive/Documents/SchoolWork/Lab3/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `Snake::display()'
c:/Users/viens/OneDrive/Documents/SchoolWork/Lab3/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Snake::bite()'
c:/Users/viens/OneDrive/Documents/SchoolWork/Lab3/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `Snake::display()'
c:/Users/viens/OneDrive/Documents/SchoolWork/Lab3/main.cpp:37: undefined reference to `Snake::bite()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Comment: What compiler are you using with VS code? Most likely you are just compiling main.cpp and not Snake.cpp, hence it can't find the definition for this functions

Comment: I'm using MinGW g++ to build the active file and running it through the VScode terminal. When trying to build Snake.cpp it says error: redefinition of 'Snake::Snake()' but all the examples my professor provided has done it this way

Comment: they're all in the same folder so my include is correct.

Comment: i figured it out, it was because in snake.h i had the functions open but they needed to be closed because i declared it somewhere else

Comment: You need to compile all files and not just `main.cpp`. If you compile only `main.cpp` then `#include "Snake.h"` will still work (`main.cpp` will "see" the signatures in the `Snake` class) and `main.cpp` compiles just fine, but when generating the executable the compiler needs to link everything together and at that stage it does not find the implementations of the methods in the `Snake` class. Thus you get undefined reference erros **during the linking**.

Comment: Your bug is most likely in your `tasks.json` file

Comment: Visual Studio Code is a tricky beast to wrangle. I do not recommend it to people trying to learn C++ because they wind up having to learn two things and can't effectively learn the important one, C++, until after they've learned care and feeding of Visual Studio Code. This may change in a few years , but for now you're probably better off with a pre-configured IDE like Visual Studio.

Comment: My tasks.json is this

```{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw32\\bin"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `"${file}",` is the part having the bug. That means compile only the active file and not all the cpp files you have in your workspace folder.

Comment: @drescherjm I took that out and tried compiling and still had an issue with my exe saying it cant be ran and isnt compatible with the version of windows im running

Comment: You don't want to take that out. Taking it out means compile no files, g++ won't be happy with no files to compile. You want to replace it with the names all the .cpp files in separate arguments or use a wildcard that evaluates to all cpp files in your workspace.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-ccp-source-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-ccp-source-files)

Comment: everything is in the same folder and I changed it to this ``` "args": [
        "-g",
        "${Snake.cpp}",
        "${main.cpp}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],``` but it still isn't working properly.

Comment: @drescherjm that worked, thanks!

Comment: I don't think you wanted the `${` and `}` part around the file name. A variable in this syntax is prefixed with `${` and ended with `}` so a file names in the default folder would just be "Snake.cpp", "main.cpp", however what may trip you up  is what exactly is the default folder. You may need to use a relative path if your source files are not in this folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It compiled regularly after I removed the bodies of constructors in the header file.

```
/* Snake.h
*/
Snake();
Snake(string color, double length, bool venomous);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's an **undefined reference error**, usually it's because the `.o` file (which gets created from the `.cpp` file) doesn't exist and your compiler/build system is not able to link it.

You can use this in **CLI**: `g++ main.cpp other.cpp etc.cpp`

Comment: I dunno about usually. It looks to be true for this case, but a lot of the time it's a silly typo. or the prototype not matching the implementation.