# Undefined reference to error when building c++ programs with multiple .cpp source files using VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linker

I've installed Microsoft VSCode under Linux Mint, and opened a folder named **test1** containing 3 files:

> **test.cpp** - pre-declares **foo()** and **bar()**, then calls both functions in **main()**
> **foo.cpp** - defines function **foo()**
> **bar.cpp** - defines function **bar()**

When I compile **test.cpp** (using **F5 Start debugging** in VSCode) it fails with *undefined reference to **foo**()* and *undefined reference to **bar**()*. When I compile **foo.cpp** and **bar.cpp,** they both fail with *undefined reference to **main**.*

I found [VS Code will not build c++ programs with multiple .ccp source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-ccp-source-files) as asked here previously, from which I discover I can type the following in the VSCode "Terminal" window...

> **g++ test.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp -o a.out**
> **./a.out**

...and my program compiles and runs as expected (but I can't do any debugging, obviously).

---

So what I want to know in the first instance is *How do I tell VSCode to compile and link in those two additional source files?*

Unless it's going to be blindingly difficult, I'd also like some guidance on how to go about moving on to Phase 2 of my task - compiling **foo** and **bar** into a "library" file that I can link across to when working on a project in folder **test2** (sibling to **test1**).

If at all possible, I'd like to achieve this entirely within the context of the VSCode environment (maybe I'll think about learning the complexities of g++ and makefiles sometime in the future).

Comment: The documentation tells you exactly what to do. The change needed is right here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: Thanks. It took me a while to figure out that the reason it still didn't work when I did ***exactly*** what  it told me in your link (without giving a particularly enlightening error message) was because I edited tasks.json as instructed, to use *an argument like "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp" instead of ${file}*. But the **double backslashes** part of that must be relevant to a Windows environment. Eventually I thought of replacing it with a single *forward* slash **/**, which did the trick. Maybe I'm not making enough effort, but I could have used better help than that.

Comment: There is other documentation for linux or macOS that show using / instead of \ for the same modifying tasks.json. I guess because you mentioned linux mint I should have linked that instead.

Comment: The linux documentation mentions the change here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: That being the case, why did you give me a link to documentation aimed at a *Windows* user? I made it clear in the quesztion I'm on Linux Mint. Anyway, thanks for the updated link.

Comment: I don't think I'm that dumb, but I kinda thought VSCode might be smart enough by now to present me with some kind of controlled GUI "project properties / definition"  input screen where I'd be asked to identify additional source files, libraries, etc. I didn't want to have to learn g++ command line syntax, which is what editing that .json file seems to amount to. Whatever - thanks very much for your help

Comment: I think with VSCode if you want to do anything complex you will have to learn your compiler's syntax. It works great for single file programs that don't link to external libraries but once you surpass that you will have to edit some json files and understand the command line for your compiler.

Comment: Unless someone is going to post a really basic "step-by-step" guide to creating and linking to a library (as opposed to posting links to documentation that's bound to be much harder for me to take in), I guess I'm done here for now. But is it reasonable for me to just leave this question open anyway?

Comment: To be honest I would like to see a good answer (one that more than just links to the documentation) for this question since it comes up often for all operating systems. There are a few other older duplicates for this.

Comment: Good. On that basis, I will leave it open. I know I'm fully intending to be somewhat lazy about getting to grips with coding in C++ under Linux Mint. I also know that many if not most respondents in the Linux world (and specifically SO) favour linking to (possibly more extensive and thus complex) documentation over "spoonfeeding" querents. I haven't really done any coding for a decade, and it was all in a Windows environment anyway, so just about ***anything*** that I want to do involves a lot of new concepts I'm unfamiliar with (such as "What the hell is a json file?", which I need to know).

Comment: (My first attempt to implement the required change here failed miserably. I thought I was being "cautious" by sticking # hash symbol on the front of the existing line, mistakenly supposing this would simply comment it out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the `a.out` file first and change the `/.vscode/lauch.json` file. In that file change the `"program": "whatever"` to `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out"` and if there is a `"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",` then cut that line then press F5 and the debugger should work fine.

Check out [here](https://dev.to/talhabalaj/setup-visual-studio-code-for-multi-file-c-projects-1jpi) for more clearification.

Comment: That's great, thank you! Pressing F5 does now run my program, and your link looks useful too. But before I start wading through that link, can I just ask if by any chance there's some really easy way to make the Debugger run *up to some specific line in my source code* (without having to set an actual "breakpoint", which I haven't looked into yet). I recall that in Windows MS Visual C years ago I could "Run to current cursor position" (perhaps invoked by Ctrl+F10, I disremember). Is there any equivalent to that in my current "VSCode using g++" environment?

Comment: Don't know , sorry.

Comment: okay, well thanks for your help anyway. Maybe someone else will enlighten me here. Or I'll raise another question if I can't find the answer myself after a reasonable amount of research

Answer (score 0):

I found that it wasn't particularly helpful for me to override the default output file (from ***test***) to ***a.out*** as per the question I linked to in my OP. In the end, I just amended the highlighted element in **.vscode/tasks.json** from...

> "args": [
> "-g",
> "**${file}**",
> "-o",
> ...

...to...

> "args": [
> "-g",
> "***.cpp**",
> "-o",
> ....

Pressing F5 with VSCode compiles and runs the program, just as I wanted. But I will just mention one other thing I found confusing. The output program file is simply written out as **test** (no extension) in folder **test1** (alongside the 3 source files). But when I typed **test** + ENTER into the VSCode "Terminal" window, I got no error, *but I didn't get the expected output from my program*.

It turned out this was because (a) I forgot to type **./test** and (b) there's an executable file called **test** in my **/usr/bin** folder (that's obviously nothing to do with me; it's dated earlier than when I installed Linux Mint!) I've no idea what *that* **test** program is supposed to do, but it certainly doesn't display **Hello World** the way *my* test program does!