# Build multiple .cpp files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, build

Note that I'm using Windows 10 x64, MinGW 9.2.0, VSCode 1.54.1.

My goal is to build and run multiple `.cpp` files in current folder and different levels subfolders I use. I've tried it configuring `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` files with help of these articles: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
[VS Code will not build c++ programs with multiple .ccp source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-ccp-source-files)

I tried to configure my `c_cpp_properties.json` by adding this instruction:

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/*"
            ]
```

And I modified also my `tasks.json` like this:

```
"args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ]
```

It actually works for the case I would like to build multiple `.cpp` files in the main directory. I have a folder `vscode_prj`, then I have `.vscode` inside (I attach all my configuration files here), and all files I have inside `vscode_prj` are build OK, but if I try to create a new folder inside `vscode_prj`, for example `vscode_prj/project1` and I have a few `.cpp` files inside `project1` it's not working and I can't build these files. I just recieve this error:

```
g++.exe: error: C:\Users\username\folderfolder\_prj\vscode_prj\*.cpp: Invalid argument
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

So, as I understand, compiler just can't find my source files inside subfolder. And it doesn't matter if I have one source file in this folder or several, it's just not build. I appreciate any help and excuse me for my English, it's my first question here, because I just don't know what to do. Thanks.

Attachments:
vscode_prj/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/*"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-std=c++17"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

vscode_prj/.vscode/tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

vscode_prj/.vscode/launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Сборка и отладка активного файла",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Включить автоматическое форматирование для gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

vscode_prj/.vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.tcc": "cpp",
        "iosfwd": "cpp",
        "iostream": "cpp",
        "string": "cpp",
        "iomanip": "cpp"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to change `"${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",` to `"${workspaceFolder}\\myfoldername\\*.cpp",` You can put multiple wildcard similar entries on consecutive lines. I don't know if `"${workspaceFolder}\\*\\*.cpp",` would work on windows.

Comment: You've reached the point where a build system will suit you better. cmake integrates directly with VS Code (with extension), so you still get your one-button build.

Comment: Thank you so much. Btw, this method `"${workspaceFolder}\\*\\*.cpp"` unfortunately doesn't work for me on Windows, but this one `"${workspaceFolder}\\myfoldername\\*.cpp"` works properly, it's not so conveniently I would like it to be, but it works and it's quite enough for me for now.