# Vscode g++ it isn't finding .cpp definition files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

### I'm trying to compile a c++ example with multiple .cpp and .hpp files, but g++ doesn't find any member function definition.

---

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "HELL!\n";
    
    Person a{"Jiraya"};
    std::cout << a.getName() << "\n";
    a.setName("Niko");
    a.do_smt();
}
```

Person.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

using std::string;

class Person
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    Person();
    Person(const string &n);
    void do_smt();
    string getName(){return name;}
    void setName(const string& n);
```

Person.cpp:

```
    #pragma once
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Person.hpp"
    
    Person::Person(const string &n) : name{n}
    {
    }
    
    void Person::setName(const string &n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    
    void Person::do_smt()
    {
        std::cout << "???";
    }
```

Tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-iquote${workspaceFolder}/headers"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Terminal output:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file <

Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/main.cpp -o /home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/main -iquote/home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/headers
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccN0pJKE.o: in function `main':
/home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Person::Person(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Person::setName(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Person::do_smt()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

---

### Here is the project folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

I did add `"-iquote${workspaceFolder}/headers"` arg in `tasks.json` to locate .hpp in a subdirectory. It doesn't seem to work with .cpp files. What do I do?(Even if I move `Person.cpp` to `${workspaceFolder}` results the same terminal output)

Comment: The command line you have given g++ is `/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/main.cpp -o /home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/main -iquote/home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/sandbox/headers`. There is no `Person.cpp` in there. You didn't tell g++ that it also needs to compile that file. Add it where ever you added `main.cpp`.

Comment: Please show your `tasks.json` since that is the source of the problem.

Comment: ***I did add "-iquote${workspaceFolder}/headers" arg in task.json to locate .hpp in a subdirectory. It doesn't seem to work with .cpp files.*** That is correct it has nothing to do with source files. You need to list the source files the same way as you did main.cpp or use a wildcard or several when the files are in different folders.

Comment: @drescherjm added tasks.json code

Comment: @user17732522  How do I do that?

Comment: Your bug is here: `"${file}",` it means to compile only the active file ignoring all other source files. You should replace that line with `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",` and add `"${workspaceFolder}/classes/*.cpp",` as the next line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `tasks.json` you are using the default `${file}` which means compile only the active file and not all source files in your folder structure.

The VSCode documentation explains how to fix this for the case of all source files in the same folder here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson

The fix is to replace `${file}` with `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"`

In your case you have more than 1 folder containing source files. You can apply a similar fix to the second folder by adding: `"${workspaceFolder}/classes/*.cpp"`

so the whole tasks.json would be:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/classes/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-iquote${workspaceFolder}/headers"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: For me it gives error like `cc1plus: fatal error: /testcode/*.cpp: No such file or directory`

Comment: There is a bug that the developers introduced recently in the c++ extension. It will be fixed in version 1.19.5. See here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78053449/vs-code-c-c-1-19-4-cppbuild-task-does-not-support-globbing-when-args-is-an-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78053449/vs-code-c-c-1-19-4-cppbuild-task-does-not-support-globbing-when-args-is-an-a)