# Cannot build multiple CPP files with VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I've followed the instructions here to setup VSCode with C++ on Windows 10 with MingGW
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp
and I've followed the instructions at this link to create my task to **build all .cpp files in the current folder** [VS Code will not build c++ programs with multiple .ccp source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-ccp-source-files)

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${fileDirname}\\**.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

However, when attempting to build, I'm getting this error:

```
Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\user\Documents\CPP_test\.vscode\**.cpp" -o "C:\Users\user\Documents\CPP_test\.vscode\tasks.exe"
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: C:\Users\user\Documents\CPP_test\.vscode\**.cpp: Invalid argument
compilation terminated.
```

I've tried replacing the argument with `\\*.cpp`, `/**.cpp`, `/*/*.cpp` but none of it worked. For some reason it refuses to explode the * wildcard.

How can I make VS Code build all CPP files in the folder?

Comment: 1. I would not expect your cpp files to be in this folder: `"C:\Users\user\Documents\CPP_test\.vscode\**.cpp"` 2. I am not sure the **.cpp is correct in this case but it may not hurt.

Comment: I think you need to change `"${fileDirname}\\**.cpp",` to `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",`  like in my answer from January: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856902/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856902/487892)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem has to do with the fact that I'm running the build while tasks.json is active. The problem is that **.cpp is not expanded or there is no indication that no cpp files are found. The argument itself seems to be bad, which is  clearly not the case.

Comment: Was this supposed to be an answer or a comment?