# VScode on MAC: linker command failed with exit code

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I am new to C++ using vscode on MAC and I tried to test using a sample program.

In the header file, I declare the class.

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student{
    public:
    string name;
    int rollno;

    Student();
    Student(string s, int id);
    void printDetails();
};
#endif
```

The implementation is done in the .cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;

Student::Student(){}
Student::Student(string s, int id):name(s),rollno(id){}
void Student::printDetails(){
    cout<< rollno << "-" << name<<endl;
}
```

Finally, I added `Main.cpp`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Student students[8];
    students[0] = Student("Tom", 1);
    students[1] = Student("Jerry", 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        students[i].printDetails();
    }
}
```

However, when I followed the procedures suggested in  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac . The compiler issued errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Student::printDetails()", referenced from:
      _main in Main-896002.o
  "Student::Student(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int)", referenced from:
      _main in Main-896002.o
  "Student::Student()", referenced from:
      _main in Main-896002.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The issue can be resolved by manually linking `Main.cpp` with `student.cpp`, i.e.,

```
g++ Main.cpp student.cpp -o Main
```

However, is there a more effective way to do so as the manual work is troublesome when the project size is large?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vscode g++ it isn't finding .cpp definition files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856563/vscode-g-it-isnt-finding-cpp-definition-files)

Comment: The duplicate I linked shows the problem with your tasks.json and is only valid if you are not using an extension like code-runner, CMake tools or Makefile tools

Comment: ***is there a more effective way to do so as the manual work is troublesome when the project size is large?*** You may want to use CMake tools or Makefile tools when your code becomes more complex.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!! I think that will fix the problem.