# How to configure VSCode to compile C++ project with files in different directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm new to C++ programming and VSCode. When I was moving from VS2019 to VSCode I just copied someones task.json and was happy. But now I'm trying to organise my code in structured project like this:

project_directory

- docs
- includes

  - header.h
- src

  - main.cpp
  - functions.cpp
- tests

My tasks.json looks like that:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++-11 build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++-11",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "-std=c++20",
            "${fileDirname}/**.cpp",
            "${fileDirname}/**.h",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/mainExecutable"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++-11"
    }
]
```

}

When all files were in the "project_directory" it compiled. But with current structure I have to add header file to every directory that contain .cpp files. And my executable file is now located in "src" directory. What should I change in "tasks.json" to make it compile?

Comment: use a build tool like CMake or Make

Comment: @rioV8 I know that I should, but it'll take some time and I need to push my project to GitHub to work now and I would like it to be structured properly

Comment: creating a simple Makefile is much faster done than getting this running, and a CMake project for a few C++ files might be done even faster

Comment: This answer of mine shows how to extend your tasks.json to use more than 1 folder: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856563/vscode-g-it-isnt-finding-cpp-definition-files/70856902#70856902](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856563/vscode-g-it-isnt-finding-cpp-definition-files/70856902#70856902)

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks a lot. I've get the idea from your answer and understood how to solve my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vscode g++ it isn't finding .cpp definition files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856563/vscode-g-it-isnt-finding-cpp-definition-files)