# "Fatal Error: source/math/vector2.cpp: No such file or directory" on compile but no error squiggle in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, include

I'm working on a C++ project set up in VS Code and it was working fine at first, but when trying to include a class file into another, it gives me the following error:

`fatal error: source/math/vector2.cpp: No such file or directory 5 | #include "source/math/vector2.cpp"`

This would suggest that my include path is incorrect, but VS Code does not give me an error squiggle, meaning VS Code sees the path as valid, but the compiler does not. I am aware that VS Code and the compiler are entirely separate but in the Makefile I'm using the compiler pulls the include directories from the project settings

What I thought might be the case was the fact that main.cpp is able to include vector.cpp because its in the folder "source", which both the renderer folder and the math folder are subfolders of, while referencing vector from the renderer class requires it to go up a level and then back down to a different subfolder but the problem persists when putting all files in the same folder, so that can't be it

Code is below, I don't think the contents of the renderer class would have an effect anything but I included it just in case

main.cpp

```
#include <time.h>
#include <nds.h>
#include <nf_lib.h>
#include "renderer/renderer.cpp"
#include "math/vector2.cpp"
#include "vlf_input.h"
#include "vlf_rand.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Initialize the random function
    vlf_rand::setSeed((long int)time(NULL));

    // Initialize the console
    consoleDemoInit();
    consoleClear();

    // Initialize Nitro File System
    NF_SetRootFolder("NITROFS");

    // Initialize the renderer
    Renderer renderer = Renderer();
    renderer.setBackground("bg/screen1", 256, 256, BOTTOM_SCREEN, 1);

    while(1) {
        // Input
        scanKeys();
        touchRead(&vlf_input::touch);

        // Update


        // Render
        NF_SpriteOamSet(TOP_SCREEN); 
        NF_SpriteOamSet(BOTTOM_SCREEN); 

        swiWaitForVBlank();

        oamUpdate(&oamMain);
        oamUpdate(&oamSub);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

vector2.h

```
#ifndef VECTOR2_H
#define VECTOR2_H
struct Vector2 {
    float x;
    float y;
    Vector2();
    Vector2(const float& x, const float& y);
    bool operator==(const Vector2& other);
    bool operator!=(const Vector2& other);
    Vector2 operator+(const Vector2& addend);
    Vector2 operator-(const Vector2& subtrahend);
    Vector2 operator*(const float& multiplier);
    Vector2 operator/(const float& divisor);
    float magnitude();
    Vector2 normalized();
    Vector2 clampMagnitude(const float& maxMagnitude);
};
#endif
```

vector2.cpp

```
#include <math.h>
#include "vector2.h"

Vector2::Vector2() 
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

Vector2::Vector2(const float& x, const float& y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

bool Vector2::operator==(const Vector2& other) 
{
    return (x == other.x && y == other.y);
}

bool Vector2::operator!=(const Vector2& other) 
{
    return (x != other.x || y != other.y);
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator+(const Vector2& addend)
{
    return Vector2(x + addend.x, y + addend.y);
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator-(const Vector2& subtrahend)
{
    return Vector2(x - subtrahend.x, y - subtrahend.y);
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator*(const float& multiplier)
{
    return Vector2(x * multiplier, y * multiplier);
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator/(const float& divisor)
{
    return Vector2(x / divisor, y / divisor);
}

float Vector2::magnitude()
{
    return sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
}

Vector2 Vector2::normalized() 
{
    float m = magnitude();
    if (m == 0) return Vector2();
    return Vector2(x / m, y / m);
}

Vector2 Vector2::clampMagnitude(const float& maxMagnitude)
{
    float m = magnitude();
    float multiplier = 1;
    if (m > maxMagnitude) multiplier = maxMagnitude / m;
    return Vector2(x * multiplier, y * multiplier);
}
```

renderer.h

```
#define RENDERER_H

#include <nf_lib.h>
#include "source/math/vector2.cpp"

// Screen
#define TOP_SCREEN 0
#define BOTTOM_SCREEN 1

class Renderer {
    Vector2 viewportPosition;

    static const char* getBackgroundName(u8 screen, u8 layer);
public:
    Renderer();
    ~Renderer();
    void setSpritePosition(u8 screen, u8 id);
    void changeSpriteLayer(u8 screen, u8 id, u8 layer);
    void setBackground(const char* file, u16 width, u16 height, u8 screen, u8 layer);
    void deleteBackground(u8 screen, u8 layer);
    void deleteAllBackgrounds();
    void render();
};
#endif
```

renderer.cpp

```
#include "renderer.h"
#include "source/math/vector2.cpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

Renderer::Renderer() 
{
    // Set both screens to 2D render mode
    NF_Set2D(TOP_SCREEN, 0);
    NF_Set2D(BOTTOM_SCREEN, 0);

    // Initialize the background buffers
    NF_InitTiledBgBuffers();

    // Initialize the background system
    NF_InitTiledBgSys(TOP_SCREEN);
    NF_InitTiledBgSys(BOTTOM_SCREEN);
}

Renderer::~Renderer() 
{
    deleteAllBackgrounds();
}

const char* Renderer::getBackgroundName(u8 screen, u8 layer) {
    std::string s = "";
    s += std::to_string(screen);
    s += std::to_string(layer);
    return s.c_str();
}

void Renderer::setBackground(const char* file, u16 width, u16 height, u8 screen, u8 layer) {
    // Get the background name from the screen and layer
    const char* name = getBackgroundName(screen, layer);

    // Load the background from FAT
    NF_LoadTiledBg(file, name, width, height);

    // Create the background
    NF_CreateTiledBg(screen, layer, name);

    // Delete from RAM if the background is less than 512x512
    if (width <= 512 && height <= 512)
        NF_UnloadTiledBg(name);
}

void Renderer::deleteBackground(u8 screen, u8 layer) {
    // Get the background name from the screen and layer
    const char* name = getBackgroundName(screen, layer);

    // Delete and unload the background
    NF_DeleteTiledBg(screen, layer);
    NF_UnloadTiledBg(name);
}

void Renderer::deleteAllBackgrounds() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            deleteBackground(i, j);
        }
    }
}

void Renderer::render()
{

}
```

There is a chance this is not related to anything in my code and is rather related to the compiler, but if that was the case I would likely need to seek help elsewhere as the compiler I'm using is old and pretty niche for my purposes (devkitPro and libNDS for Nintendo DS development) so I won't provide details on that here. If you know anything about that, let me know and I'll make a separate question for it and tag you.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you did not setup the include path properly so there is no "source/math/vector2.cpp" file or this is not a relative path compared to the `renderer.cpp` file meaning in the folder with `renderer.cpp` there is not also a `source` folder.

Comment: You should never include a cpp file that is not the correct approach to solve the VSCode default behavior of building only 1 source file. The documentation tells you how to fix that here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: My advice is if you are going to use many source files in VSCode and the source files are in different folders in some hierarchy you probably want to use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) and the [CMakeTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) extension to manage the building.  Without using CMake or a Makefile you will need to do something like this: [Link to an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856563/vscode-g-it-isnt-finding-cpp-definition-files/70856902#70856902)

Comment: @drescherjm I don't think CMake is an option due to the nature of my compiler but I will look into it