# Quotes around VSCode cppbuild Command While Trying to Update Build Task for the Recent Globbing Removal in Args

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In an attempt to follow the new way of [doing build tasks in v1.19.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78053449/vs-code-c-c-1-19-cppbuild-task-no-longer-supports-globbing-when-args-is-an-a) I have condensed my arguments into the command parameter of the build task since that is the only way of doing that now. I currently have the setup:

```
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active files",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++ -g -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -Weffc++ -Wno-unused-parameter -fsanitize=undefined,address ${relativeFileDirname}/*.cpp -o ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
```

But when I run it, I get:

```
Starting build...
'/usr/bin/g++ -g -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -Weffc++ -Wno-unused-parameter -fsanitize=undefined,address ${relativeFileDirname}/*.cpp -o ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}'
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/g++ -g -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -Weffc++ -Wno-unused-parameter -fsanitize=undefined,address ${relativeFileDirname}/*.cpp -o ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}: not found

Build finished with error(s).
```

I have tried various small changes to no avail and would like help on the matter. I apologize if this is a redundant post, but I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment on the original linked post and feel it should be a full on post regardless.

I tried removing the args flag, but that makes the c/c++ extension not recognize the task as a valid build task. I have tried moving only the *.cpp part into the command portion but it puts quotes around the "g++ *.cpp" part and has the rest on the outside. I have tried looking for a task variable that can mimic the * globbing feature, but found none.

Comment: Could you elaborate how I am not following it?

Comment: It tried to use `'/usr/bin/g++ -g -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -Weffc++ -Wno-unused-parameter -fsanitize=undefined,address ${relativeFileDirname}/*.cpp -o ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}'` as the name of the executable to run.

Comment: try `"command": "/usr/bin/g++", "args": "-g -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -Weffc++ -Wno-unused-parameter -fsanitize=undefined,address ${relativeFileDirname}/*.cpp -o ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"` cc @273K

Comment: If the comment from @starball works perhaps it should be made an answer. After reading this and the comments of the github issue I expect this to be a serious problem causing a flood of questions.

Comment: @drescherjm if it does work (and for me it surprisingly doesn't even though I'm pretty sure it's supposed to (I think there might be more bugs with the C/C++ extension. see my edit to my answer in the linked question)), I'm just going to add an example into my answer to the linked question and hope this question magically fades out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change to the argument escaping in 1.19.4 will be reverted so you will be able to use `"args"` again in 1.19.5.