# Visual-studio Code Compile error when adding "`imlib2-config --cflags`" in the arg section

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using VS code on UBUNTU 6.5.0-17-generic and it fail to compile the program with bellow Error:
Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -g program.c -o program -lX11 '`imlib2-config --cflags`'
**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find `imlib2-config --cflags`: No such file or directory**
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My **tasks.json args:**

```
"args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-lX11","imlib2-config --cflags"

]
```

I tried to "break the IMLIB2-CONFIG flag into two sections "`imlib2-config ", "--cflags`"
still failing with Error /usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -g program.c -o program -lX11 `imlib2-config ' --cflags`'
**/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string**

When running the same compile command from the command line as in
$ gcc -g ./program.c -o ./program -lX11 `imlib2-config --cflags` `imlib2-config --libs`

I'm expecting that compilation is successful and my "program" runs as expected

Comment: why do you have two extra backticks outside of a JSON string in your JSON array? also, what version of the cpptools extension are you on? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78058239/11107541

Comment: Hi this is my compile command $gcc -g ./focus.c -o ./focus -lX11 `imlib2-config --cflags` so I thought I will need to add it to the JSON file as is.
any way I removed them and the application fail to compile with the same file not found error

Comment: no, that's not what I'm talking about. the code block you wrote has **four** backticks in it. I understand why you put the first two there. what about the third and fourth one? Also, you still haven't answered my question about what version of the cpptools extension you're on.

Comment: cpptools ext' version is 1.19.8
and all these backticks are placed only for this webpage they are not part of my tasks.json it looks like this 

"args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g","${file}",
                "-o","${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-lX11","imlib2-config --cflags","imlib2-config --libs"
            ]
Thanks

Comment: @starball : I follow your lead on the syntax but it didn't change the behavior, Code compiler still fail to interpret the **imlib2-config --cflags** and stop with same Error **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find imlib2-config --cflags: No such file or directory**

Comment: `"imlib2-config --cflags"` -> `"imlib2-config", "--cflags"`