# Why do I get this error message: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64?

Tags: c++

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Log(char const*)", referenced from:
_main in main-cc9ca1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I am just starting to learn cpp.

in main.cpp I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Log(const char* message);


int main() {
    Log("Hello world");
    cin.get();
    
}
```

in log.cpp I have:

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;

void Log(const char* message) {
    cout << message << " hehe" << endl;
}
```

I can't seem to be able to compile it. I am doing it in visual studio code on Mac.

Comment: You need to compile and link both files. Most likely you aren't doing that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: The above suspicion can be proved one way or the other by adding the command or the build automation configuration file used to build the program to the question. Right now the best anyone can do is guess, even thought hat guess is probably correct.

Comment: I still get the same message from the visual studio code

Comment: [Give this question a read over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-cpp-source-files) and see if it help you sort out the VS Code configuration to ensure log.cpp is being built and linked.