# How can i run multiple files in C (visual studio code)?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I want to to run a simple program, using vs code, which includes three files: main.c item.c item.h.

I understand that I there is a way to link things together, but I don't know how. Can you explain me how to do it?

I've tried also to add the extension to make a project, but I didn't understand how to.

Here's the code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "item.h"


int main () {

  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;
  int res;
  res = prod(a,b);

  printf("%d ", res);

  return 0;
}
```

item.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "item.h"

int prod(int a, int b) {
    return a*b;
}
```

item .h

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

int prod(int a, int b);

#endif
```

Comment: I'm assuming visual studio code uses a json or some makefile, where is that file?

Comment: Which extension are you using?

Comment: https://iraspa.org/blog/visual-studio-code-c-cpp-fortran-with-multiple-source-files/  -> is that helpful

Comment: Do you get any error message when compiling ?

Comment: If you use multiple C/C++ files you should use a build tool CMake/Make/MSBuild/....

Comment: @YvesDaoust , yes, i should have mentioned it. I get this
undefined reference to `prod' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code will not build c++ programs with multiple .ccp source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-ccp-source-files)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using Windows or Linux or Mac, I'm going to explain it for Linux but the method is similar for the others.

First of you go on VS Code, then you click on new file and rename it "makefile", then you write this:

```
link: item.o main.o 
     gcc item.o main.o -o programName

main.o:
     gcc -c main.c

item.o: 
     gcc -c item.c

clear:
     rm -f item.o main.o programName //this one is to delete files faster
```

Once you wrote the makefile you write in the terminal the command `make` and you get the executable file for your program.

However in `item.c` you aren't using any of the library you included, you only need to include `item.h`; last thing, I don't know why you are doing the `#ifndef` thing but it seems a waste.