# unable to use headers with vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linker, header-files

I am trying to use headers in vscode but I run through a lot of problems

this is **print.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print1to10()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

this is **print.h**

```c
#ifndef PRINT_TO_10_H
#define PRINT_TO_10_H

#include <stdio.h>
void print1to10();

#endif
```

this is the main file **main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "print.h"

int main()
{
    print1to10();
    return 0;
}
```

Just a simple program but it seems that vscode doesn't like it
and it gives me this error
`K:/test/main.c:6: undefined reference to 'print1to10' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

**one more thing**
I don't know if it is relevant or not but I have played a little bit with C/C++ Configurations

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22000.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I tried putting the **print.c** & **print.h** files in another folder in the same folder but then it gives me another error that it cannot even find the header file

```
  K:\test\main.c:2:10: fatal error: print.h: No such file or directory
  2 | #include "print.h"
    |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Error `undefined reference to 'print1to10'` is linker error, not compiler error. So it has nothing to do with header file `print.h`. Linker cannot find `print1to10` function which to add to the executable. Either you are not building `print.c` file, or you have not included resulting `print.o` file into your linking step. (Unfortunately I don't know how this is done in VSCode.)

Comment: Sidenote: Function `void print1to10()` should be declared as `void print1to10(void)` in C because it takes no arguments.

Comment: Sidenote: You only need to include `stdio.h` in `print.c` because that is the only place you use `printf`. It is not harmful, just unnecessary. It is also recommended for extra safety that you include `print.h` in `print.c` to make compiler check that your `print1to10` function declaration and definition signatures match. This will protect you from accidental typos.

Comment: show how you build. likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47665886/11107541.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are having is that the file ***print.c*** is not linked to the executable. That's why the function ***print1to10*** is undefined.

When I run your main.c with the extension [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) it generates the following file in the folder ***.vscode***

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

With this you can add the file ***print.c*** in the ***args*** section, so it'd look like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "${fileDirname}\\print.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

This will basically do the following command:

```
gcc main.c print.c -o main.exe
```

For more information you can check the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

Additionally I modified a bit your code to remove redundace, however what you have should compile correctly.

**print.h**

```
// Changed PRINT_TO_10_H to PRINT_H since the name of the
// file is print.h
#ifndef PRINT_H
# define PRINT_H

#include <stdio.h>

void    print1to10(void);

#endif
```

**print.c**

```
// Removed stdio.h because is already included in print.h

#include "print.h"

void    print1to10(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

**main.c**

```
// Removed stdio.h because is already included in print.h
// besides it is not used in this file.
#include "print.h"

int main(void)
{
    print1to10();
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: I have every file in the same folder, if you want to organise them in multiple folders, [Usman  Mehwood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77660186/20529690)'s answer is very accurate!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multiple files of multiple folders, for example with the following structure:

```
project
 |
 |- library_1
 |   |
 |   |- library_1.h
 |   |- library_1.c
 |
 |- main.c
```

you can pass something like this to GCC.

```bash
gcc main.c -I ./library_1 library_1/library_1.c -o program.exe
```

And it would compile.

Alternatively you can try my VSCode extension that takes care of all the build configurations, running, debugging etc and also helps you create new, multi-library projects.

It's called [C Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit)