# What's the difference between pressing F5 and clicking the run button (at the top right) on a C or C++ project in VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I recently was able to setup raylib on my linux laptop, and I had a bit of trouble as I wasn't comfortable with compilers, but after using the VS Code project template from raylib and editing one of files in the .vscode directory it worked. Pressing F5 compiles and runs the project in a debugger mode. But when I try to click the UI button for running it using GCC and a bunch of other options in the drop down menu, it doesn't compile and gives a bunch of undefined function errors.

What I would like to know is the difference between pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, which seems to compile everything without issue, and pressing the "Run C Code" play button. None of the options for pressing the run button work and all result in undefined function errors. According to VS Code, <kbd>F5</kbd> "runs" the code, but I don't know exactly what it does, and what commands it follows, and why it's different from the "Run C/C++ Code" button.

[image: Screenshot of my project directory]

[The project template that I used](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/tree/master/projects/VSCode)

Comment: What is this "Run C Code" button? That is not a part of VS Code itself. Presumably it's some extension you installed

Comment: Do you understand what the files in the `.vscode` folder are for and have you tried  to modify them? Does pressing F5 still work if your project have more than one source file?

Comment: @UnholySheep This is the button I'm talking about [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/wqoUatZ)

Comment: @WeijunZhou No, I don't really understand what files like c_cpp_properties.json are for. I know that files in .vscode are vscode specific, but I don't know what most of the files do. I know that launch.json is for the run button, but it doesn't seem like F5 runs any of the tasks in launch.json.

Comment: So your F5 is just a single file runner. I think it'll break down if you have multiple files. Don't rely on it. Write a proper json instead.

Comment: I'll try to learn how all the files in .vscode work tomorrow, and then I think I'll be able to write my own launch.json configuration, instead of blindly relying on someone else's run task.

Comment: Follow the official guide [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) and good luck.

Comment: Run button is likely powered by an extension, like this one [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hBbaJN_D94).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just have the C/C++ extension installed and not something else that also contributes features for building and running C or C++ programs,

Assuming you haven't changed your default VS Code keybindings in a way that changes this, the relevant default VS Code keybinding for <kbd>F5</kbd> here is this:

```json
{
  "key": "f5",
  "command": "workbench.action.debug.start",
  "when": "debuggersAvailable && debugState == 'inactive'"
},
```

That command will just start the selected launch configuration. Same as pressing the run button in the Run and Debug View (yes, there are two play buttons that do different things. yes, it's confusing).

As for the run button in the top right of the workbench, that's also contributed by the C/C++ extension and gives you the option to debug (run with a debugger) or run (run without a debugger) the current file (at least, by default, that's what it's geared toward doing). Clicking the button should present you with a menu to select how you want to build and debug, and it will at least contain several "detected" / auto-generated options based on the build tools you have installed in common places on your machine.

Using those detected / auto-generated options from that menu probably fail to build because their compile / link flags don't match what your program needs to be built properly. Ex. compiling multiple source files and linking their object files together.

But you can add options to that menu, and you can give the button a default behaviour by defining default build tasks. For more info on that, see my answer to [What's the difference between the "Debug C/C++ File", "Run Code", and "Run C/C++ code" buttons in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77652090/11107541). If you need to build a program from multiple source files, see also [VS Code will not build c++ programs with multiple .cpp source files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47665886/11107541).

As a final note, I recommend that you learn CMake. Then you can configure builds in a way that is cross platform and mostly independent of what developer tooling (Ex. IDE) you're using. And as your programs scale larger, the builds will be more efficient than always recompiling everything even when not needed (you configure CMake to generate buildsystems, and those buildsystems will know when a source file needs to be recompiled, and when an executable or library needs to be rebuilt).

---

Note that if you are using CMake Tools, it also contributes <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> for `CMake: Debug`, and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> for `CMake: Run Without Debugging`.

Comment: Nicely covered.  And thanks for being kind to this user.