Args not passing using lldb launch.json file in VS Code
My launch.json file inn VS Code looks like the following:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [
                "-e",
                "smile.png",
                "not_smile.png",
                "ABCD"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
    ]
}

And my main.cpp contains:
int main(int argc, char** argv) {}
The debugger says that there's only one argument that says "/". Any advice?

are you sure the name of your executable is enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out?

Even if I change it to the respective program, it's not reading correctly

That is important because if the actual name of the executable was different maybe this launch.json was not being used at all for some reason.

how are you running? read https://stackoverflow.com/q/77646301/11107541

Your launch.json is most likely not valid, considering the target executable currently is enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out, which I highly doubt is the name of your executable.
It is most likely not actually used at all.
To verify, can you confirm that in your VSCode, your chosen lauch configuration looks like this?


I just set up a small test program on Windows and it works fine. This is my c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22000.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

And this is my launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "HERE IS THE PATH TO YOUR EXECUTABLE",
            "args": [    "-e",
            "smile.png",
            "not_smile.png",
            "ABCD"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}

