How to type input in while debugging in vs code
Having issue with writing input into program while debugging in Visual Studio Code.
New to VS code and I am debugging my C program with user written input from stdin, but I am unable to write in input into the integrated terminal while debugging as it will close if I type in any key. I have the codeRunner extension downloaded and the "run in integrated terminal" checked and this issue is still persisting. One solution I found to this was setting externalConsole to true and typing in my input there, but it is not ideal since every time I want to debug, I get a tons of terminal tabs opened up. I'm hoping there's an alternative solution to this because I have a friend that can type in his input into his terminal while debugging just fine. I am on Mac for reference.

how exactly are you running? read https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652228/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77646301/11107541. have you checked that this question is not answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/77357008/11107541 or other answers in that Q&A?
