# Building multiple C++ files simultaneously in VSCode on Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc

I am attempting to modify my tasks.json file in VSCode such that VSCode will build all C++ files in my project's directory simultaneously.

I've followed the instructions on [the VSCode website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson) so that `args` looks like this,

```
"args": [
    "-g",
    "-std=c++2a",
    "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}/rooster"
],
```

but it's throwing an error: `/home/dcusick/Documents/C++ projects/*.cpp: No such file or directory`

Trying to compile using the terminal instead of VSCode, I get the following result:

```
(base) dcusick@T15g:~$ g++ -g "/home/dcusick/Documents/C++ projects/"*.cpp -o /home/dcusick/Documents/C++\ projects/rooster
(base) dcusick@T15g:~$ g++ -g "/home/dcusick/Documents/C++ projects/*.cpp" -o /home/dcusick/Documents/C++\ projects/rooster
g++: error: /home/dcusick/Documents/C++ projects/*.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Compiling is actually successful when the quotation mark ends before the asterisk. Can someone help me understand what is happening here and how to appropriately modify my tasks.json file? Of course I could just use the terminal to compile each time, but that would be silly; I want VSCode to do the compiling for me.

Comment: Recommendation: Lose the space in the folder path. The tend to bring nothing but pain. In windows you need to change `${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp` to `${workspaceFolder}/**.cpp`. Not sure about Linux, but it's a quick change worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions. The double asterisk didn't help. I'll edit my post and replace the image with text.

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-cpp-source-files#comment133076023_59236875) suggests the space in the path may be the villain.

Comment: Change `C++ projects` to `C++Projects` or `C++_projects` and things would be easier. It's best to avoid using spaces in paths or filenames in c++ or c

Comment: That was it! Removing the space from the path fixed everything. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: the space in the folder path was the villian, as the comments on this post suggested. I renamed the folder and it works.

Comment: This is tool specific. For example, the "real" Visual Studio uses space in paths by default, and that has always worked.